# ASP.NET Web Forms "Individual Accounts" not redirecting to login page for not logged in users

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I looked everywhere for my specific situation and I can't find it anywhere.

I am new to ASP.NET and I recently created an ASP.NET Web Forms project with Individual Accounts ENABLED.

I know that if this option is selected it uses ASP.Net Identity but I cant find anywhere on how to make it so only logged in accounts can access the website specifically with Web Forms Selected when the project is created.

I just want it so not logged in accounts are redirected back to the log-in page.

I don't know where else to go and if any of you guys can help a newbie like me I would be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is some example.

In your project you have one file with the name web.config.

Add in inside in the section <system.web> --> authentication and authorization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gfy0.png)

This is a usefull link that you could need:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fa9d0d/forms-authentication-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Okay, so this creates an interesting bug. It denies access to everything in the site including the login page - so when I do this, it correctly redirects back to the login page but it even denies access to the login page as well... Is it possible to make it so access is allowed for the login page? or just deny access to specific pages?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you very much for the help, it put me in the right direction on what to do!!